# Getting the error: 'Cannot read property 'then' of undefined' when trying to get current account details in React-Native

Tags: react-native

For some reason i cannot call getAccount when i am inside the App.tsx file. I am trying to check whether or not a user is currently logged in, but i am met with the error described in the question when getAccount gets called.

This is my App.tsx:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { NativeStackNavigationProp } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import LoginPage from './pages/login';
import sessions from './pages/sessions';
import { AccountContextProvider } from './context/account';
import { EventProvider } from 'react-native-outside-press';
import { FilterContextProvider } from './context/filter';
import { AccountContext } from './context/account';
import React from 'react';
import { getUserAPI } from './api/user';
import { RouteProp } from '@react-navigation/native';

export type RootStackParamList = {
  'Login Page': undefined;
  'Sessions Page': { user: any };
  'App' : undefined
};
export type SessionsPageRouteProp = RouteProp<RootStackParamList, 'Sessions Page'>;

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>(); 


const App = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState<any>(undefined);
  const { getAccount, isLogged } = React.useContext(AccountContext);
  const getUser = async (session: any) => {
    const data = await getUserAPI(session);
    setUser(data);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("getting account")
    getAccount().then((session: any) => {
        console.log("account got")
        getUser(session);
      })
      .catch(() => setUser(undefined));
  }, [isLogged]);
  
  return (
    <View>
      <AccountContextProvider>
        <EventProvider>
          <FilterContextProvider>
            <NavigationContainer>
                <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='Sessions Page' screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
                  <Stack.Screen name={'Login Page'} component={LoginPage} ></Stack.Screen>
                  <Stack.Screen name={'Sessions Page'} component={sessions} initialParams={{user: user}} ></Stack.Screen>
                  <Stack.Screen name={'App'} component={App} ></Stack.Screen>
                </Stack.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
          </FilterContextProvider>
        </EventProvider>
      </AccountContextProvider>
    </View>
    
    
    
  
  );
}

export default App;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

And this is the code, where getAccount is defined:

```
import React from "react";
import { CognitoUser, AuthenticationDetails } from "amazon-cognito-identity-js";
import userPool from "../utils/userPool";
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

let isLogged: boolean | undefined;

const authenticate: any = async (username: string, password: string) => {};
const getAccount: any = () => {};
const logout: any = () => {};

const AccountContext = createContext({
  authenticate,
  getAccount,
  logout,
  isLogged,
});

const AccountContextProvider = (props: any) => {
  console.log("AccountContextProvider initialized");
  const [isUserLogged, setIsUserLogged] = useState<boolean>(true);
  
  const getAccount = async () =>
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const user = userPool.getCurrentUser();
      console.log("Debug getaccount")
      if (user) {
        user.getSession((err: any, account: any) => {
          console.log("user", user)
          if (err) {
            setIsUserLogged(false);
            reject();
          } else {
            // console.log(account.accessToken.jwtToken);
            setIsUserLogged(true);
            resolve(account);
          }
        });
      } else {
        setIsUserLogged(false);
        reject();
      }
    });

  const authenticate = async (username: string, password: string) =>
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const user = new CognitoUser({ Username: username, Pool: userPool });
      const authDetails = new AuthenticationDetails({
        Username: username,
        Password: password,
      });
      user.authenticateUser(authDetails, {
        onSuccess: (data) => {
          setIsUserLogged(true);
          //console.log("onSuccess:", data);
          resolve(data);
        },

        onFailure: (err) => {
          setIsUserLogged(false);
          //console.error("onFailure:", err);
          reject(err);
        },

        newPasswordRequired: (data) => {
          //console.log("newPasswordRequired:", data);
          resolve(data);
        },
      });
    });

  const logout = () => {
    const user = userPool.getCurrentUser();
    if (user) {
      setIsUserLogged(false);
      user.signOut();
    }
  };

  return (
    <AccountContext.Provider
      value={{
        authenticate,
        getAccount,
        logout,
        isLogged: isUserLogged,
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </AccountContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { AccountContextProvider, AccountContext };
```

I have no problem with using the authenticate function to log users in on the login page.
Hope someone can spot what the problem is, cause I have had no  luck.

The whole application should be wrapped in the AccountContextProvider, and it does not print anything when i log something inside the getAccount function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make getAccount `async` should fix the issue

```
import React from "react";
import { CognitoUser, AuthenticationDetails } from "amazon-cognito-identity-js";
import userPool from "../utils/userPool";
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

let isLogged: boolean | undefined;

const authenticate: any = async (username: string, password: string) => {};
const getAccount: any = async () => new Promise(); //Make this function async
const logout: any = () => {};
```